# How to convert lat long into world region?

Tags: regionalization

I have a list of lat/lon points in a kml file which I would like to group into world regions. How can I use the [World Borders Dataset](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php) or some other dataset to generate a "region" tag for each point?

Answer (score 1):

if you can find a data which contains "region" column as administrative areas or boundries in polygon, you can union them in qgis. with this way you will get region parameter for all your point..

```
Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Union
```

you will see the changes when you look at your attribute table..

[image: union]

i hope it helps you....

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you're suggesting here. I don't think you can Union two layers with different types of features.

Comment: you are merging attributes not features. i am wonder whether trying or not?

Comment: I don't really understand your suggestion, and I'm also looking for a way to achieve this programmatically, is this possible with Quantum GIS? I've not used it before.

Comment: yes, it is possible with Quantum GIS and pls give detailed information in your que. you dont specify to achieve this programmatically that how can understand your needs. i hope it helps you..